# Save pictures in a folder and display them in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, gridview

I have these controls on my page:

> ```
> <p>
>     <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
> </p>
> <p>
>     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
> </p>
> <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
> </asp:GridView>
> ```

There is a foolder with the name "UplPics" in my solution explorer and the below VB.NET code in my Defaul.aspx page:

```
Imports System.IO

Partial Class _Default

 Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     If Not IsPostBack Then
         Dim filePaths As String() = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/UplPics/"))
         Dim files As New List(Of ListItem)()
         For Each filePath As String In filePaths
             Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
             files.Add(New ListItem(fileName, "~/UplPics/" + fileName))
         Next
         GridView1.DataSource = files
         GridView1.DataBind()
     End If

 End Sub

 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
         Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
         FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UplPics/") + fileName)
         Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
     End If

 End Sub 
End Class
```

When I upload and load my web page it does not show the pictures but show the URL of each picture, how could I show the pictures instead of their URL?

Comment: Well because thats exactly what you are getting...you need to have an image column..

Comment: How should I change it to show the picture in the gridview cells?

Comment: An image column. You can create a bitmap from the location and add it to a listof bitmap then set it as your datasource. Your already getting the image location you can create a bitmap from it.

Comment: I can not make it, May you plz help me? Thanks

Comment: Go to your datagrid and set your first column to an image column. You can get your bitmaps like this: Dim Image1 As New Bitmap(yourpath) then add it to your listof bitmap. Then set that as your datasource

Comment: Iam new with it, But thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After GridView bound to that data source control. This GridView would have 1 BoundField columns, meaning that instead of seeing the actual image we'd see the actual image path when viewing the GridView in a browser. Notedown the column name of image path column.

Now, To display the actual image, we need to edit the GridView's columns, Add a new BoundField say ImageField. Then, set the ImageField's DataImageUrlField to the name of the DataSource field that contains the image path (the column name noted above).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx

Comment: @user1605859: you are welcome and if you are satisfied with the answer, you can mark as answer or mark answer is useful.